# How to fix dynamic textview position problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to generate textviews dynamically. I create it but. output gives first letter at the beginning and others sorting end of the context.

```
ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
    letters.add("Y");
    letters.add("Ü");
    letters.add("Z");
    letters.add("S");
    letters.add("Ü");
    letters.add("Z");


    LinearLayout llTv = findViewById(R.id.llTv);

    TextView tv;

    for (int j = 0; j<sQuestion.length(); j++)
    {

        View main_view = new View(MainActivity.this);
        main_view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(main_view.getLayoutParams());
        lP.setMargins(10 ,10,10,10);
        llTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setText(letters.get(j));
        tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        tv.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        tv.setLinksClickable(true);
        tv.setTextSize(25);

        llTv.addView(tv,lP);
        llTv.addView(main_view,1);
    }
```

https://i.hizliresim.com/0RBDVL.png

[image: letters.png]
how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain exactly what the problem is. Also, please upload images here directly, by clicking [the image button above the edit box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRAP7.png). I can't view the image you've linked. It's giving a 403.

Comment: In our country imgur is forbidden. Is it working now?

Comment: Yeah, it's here, and I understand what you mean, now. Your problem is this call: `llTv.addView(main_view,1);`. The second argument there is the index that the `View` is inserted at. Every one of your `main_view`s – which I assume you're using as spacers – is being added at index 1, so they end up all grouped together. If you are indeed using those as spacers, then just remove that second argument; i.e., `llTv.addView(main_view);`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is working fine now =)

Answer (score 0):

Use with text view

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks for help.I already tried it. It is still the same. nothings change. I sort textviews after then this happened.